# java.lang.IllegalStateException whenever I try to add values into a populated RealmList<MyObject>

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I'm trying to add new items insedi a RealmList but I'm getting this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Changing Realm data can only be done from inside a transaction.
```

Do you know why it is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not inside a transaction.

Comment: Please can you share code that returns this exception?

Comment: @chrylis I added a transaction as suggested and it worked!! :D thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be inside a [Realm Transaction](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.Transaction.html) to add a new item in this list. The fllowing code si an example how to do it:

```
    realm.beginTransaction();
    RealmQuery query = realm.where(YourClass.class);
    RealmResults results = query.findAll();
    results.add(newItem);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

I hope it can be helpful.